# How to DRYly subclass (or otherwise share code with) rubys OptionParser to e.g. share options?

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I want to share certain options for multiple scripts and prefer to use the 'builtin' optparse over other cli-or-optionparsing-frameworks.

I quickly looked at MRIs optparse.rb and do not understand how best to sublass OptionParser (the initializer takes a block).

Optimally I would like to arrive at a code like this

```
# exe/a_script
require 'mygem'

options = {whatever: 'default'}
Mygem::OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('--whatever') do |w|
    options[:whatever] = w
  end
end.parse!
```

And a second script as consumer:

```
# exe/other_script
require 'mygem'


options = {and_another: 'default'}
Mygem::OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('--and_another') do |a|
    options[:and_another] = w
  end
end.parse!
```

And define "default option" (say "-v" for verbose and "-h" for help" in a common custom OptionParser.

```
# lib/mygem/mygem_optionparser.rb
require 'optparse'
module Mygem
  class OptionParser < OptionParser
    # magic
    # define opts.on("-v") -> set options[:verbose],
    # define opts.on_tail("-h", "print help and exit") ...
  end
end
```

Both scripts should end up having and handling the "-h" and "-v" flags, ideally filling up the "options" hash, but probably exposing it to something like Mygem::OptionParser#default_option_values.

Where do I start? Or is there a clever way of handling this differently, e.g.

```
# exe/b_script
OptionParser.new do |opts|
  define_custom_opts(opts)
end
```

I wonder that I have not found any tutorial or example on this scenario, I assume it is not such a rare use-case. And yes, I absolutely want to stick to 'optparse'.

*Update* I got confused, not looking at the correct optpase-source and thus not seeing that it yields self (which freaked me out a bit :) . Great answers so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used OptionParser so there may be a better way to do this, but I'll take a stab at it anyway.

The most important thing about [`OptionParser#initialize`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.3.0/OptionParser.html#method-c-new) (for our purposes) is that it yields `self` to the block given. To make a subclass that works the same, all we have to do is make its `initialize` method yield `self`, too:

```
require 'optparse'
require 'ostruct'

module MyGem
  class OptionParser < ::OptionParser
    attr_reader :options

    def initialize(*args)
      @options = OpenStruct.new

      super *args
      default_options!

      yield(self, options) if block_given?
    end

    private
    def default_options!
      on '--whatever=WHATEVER' do |w|
        options.whatever = w
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This calls `super` with all of the passed arguments *except* the passed block (if given). Then it calls `default_options!` to create those default options (this could have done by passing a block to `super`, but I find the above much cleaner).

Finally, it yields to the given block just as the superclass did, but it passes a second argument, the options object. The user can then use it like this:

```
require 'my_gem/option_parser'

opts = MyGem::OptionParser.new do |parser, options|
  parser.on '--and-another=ANOTHER' do |a|
    options.another = a
  end
end

opts.parse!
p opts.options
```

This would give the user results like the following:

```
$ ruby script.rb --whatever=www --and-another=aaa
#<OpenStruct whatever="www", another="aaa">
```

As an alternative to `yield(self, options)`, we could use `yield self`, but then the user would need to do e.g. `parser.options.whatever = ...` inside the block.

Another alternative would be to add a `&block` argument to `initialize` and then do `instance_eval(&block)` instead of `yield`. This would evaluate the block in the instance context, so the user could access the `options` attribute (and all other instance methods, etc.) directly, e.g.:

```
parser = MyGem::OptionParser.new do
  on '--and-another=ANOTHER' do |a|
    options.another = a
  end
end

parser.parse!
```

That has the downside, however, that the user must know that the block will be evaluated in the instance context. Personally I prefer the explicit `yield(self, options)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing at the original code. I must totally have messed up, looking at some other optparse. The yield(self, options) looks neat, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `DefaultOptParser` with default options parsing.

```
# default_parser.rb
require 'optparse'
require 'ostruct'

class DefaultOptParser
    attr_accessor :options

    def initialize
        @options = OpenStruct.new

        @parser = OptionParser.new do |opts|
          opts.banner = "Usage: example.rb [options]"

          opts.on("-v", "--[no-]verbose", "Run verbosely") do |v|
            options.verbose = v
          end
        end
    end

    def parse
        @parser.parse!
        @options
    end
end

p DefaultOptParser.new.parse
```

When you run above code,

```
> ruby default_parser.rb -v
#<OpenStruct verbose=true>
```

---

Next define a class that is child of above class and adds additional options parsing.

```
# basic_parser.rb
require_relative "default_parser"

class BasicModeParser < DefaultOptParser
    def initialize
        super
        @parser.on("-b", "--basic-mode", "Basic mode operation") do |v|
            options.basic = v
        end
    end
end

p BasicModeParser.new.parse
```

When you run above code,

```
> ruby basic_parser.rb -v -b
#<OpenStruct verbose=true, basic=true>
```

---

The above works based on my current understanding of `OptionParser`.